# Angular Library failed to export class - Angular6

Tags: model, angular6, angular-library

I have created a new Angular 6 Library. This Library has a Model called User:

```
export class User {
    public id: string;
    public username: string;

    constructor(id: string,
                username: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

I am using the library in another angular app, everything works fine. But when I try to use the model:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public user: User;

  constructor() {
    this.user = new User('1', 'my user');
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'my-lib/lib/models/user.model' in 'C:\my-app\src\app'
```

The intellisense found it but I am still receiving this error.

AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    UserModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

anybody has an idea? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest inside your lib you create a new file `public_api.ts` within `my-lib/` in which you `export` the classes you want to be publically available. You can do that by adding `export * from './lib/models/user.model` for each model, you want to export.

Comment: Perfect! it works for me, thanks!

Comment: Great, I will prepare an official answer quickly. I was on phone when I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you did not export the model to the outside world of your library.
In order to do that I suggest an additional file called `public_api.ts` in which you export the model explicitly.
Place it right into the root of your library `my-lib`.

Then, fill the file up with explicit exports like so:

```
export * from './lib/models/user.model'
```

That should do it.

Comment: i actually did this but it doesnt work. both class and interface cannot be found in the web application when i import them.

Comment: @chitgoks You should open your own question then. This answer is specific to the question posted by OP.